# Show different categories on a heatmap in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, ggmap

I created a shiny app that the user can choose some value in the checkbox and to set the date range.
I have created the ui but than the plot doesn't work in the main function.

My shiny app:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

bbox = c(left=-95.8, bottom=29.4, right=-95.0, top=30.0)
map <- get_stamenmap(bbox, zoom = 10, source="stamen")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Location"),
  sidebarPanel('Choose the type of offense to show in plot:',
               checkboxGroupInput("offense", label = "Type of offenses...",
                                  choices = list("Murder" = 'murder',
                                                 "Robbery" = 'robbery',
                                                 "Aggravated assault" = 'aggravated assault',
                                                 "Burglary" = 'burglary',
                                                 "Rape" = 'rape'),
                                  selected = 'Murder'),
               dateRangeInput("date", "Date range:",
                              start  = "2010-01-01",
                              end    = "2010-12-08",
                              min    = "2010-01-01",
                              max    = "2010-12-08",
                              format = "yyyy/mm/dd",
                              separator = " - ")
  ),
  mainPanel('Performance Plot',
            plotOutput('myplot')),
  position = 'left')



server <- function(input, output){
  output$myplot <- renderPlot(
    {
      req(input$type)
      data <- data_4 %>% filter(offense %in% input$offense)
      date <- data_4 %>% filter(offense %in% input$date)
      ggmap(map) + stat_density2d(data = subset(data,offense == "offense" & date == "date"),
                                  aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), geom = 'polygon') +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
        scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 0.8)) +
        geom_point(data = subset(data, offense == input$offense),
                   aes(x = lon, y = lat), size = 0.5) + 
        guides(fill = FALSE, alpha = FALSE) +
        ggtitle('Crime ')
      
    }
  )
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I am not sure where went wrong but I am thinking is the ggplot inside the server function. I am able to create the plot outside of shiny. but not sure how to sort out the date range and checkboxes option.
Can anyone help? I want to create multiple plot inside the main panel as users can choose more than one value from the checkboxes. But I don't know where should I put the grid.arrange function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are several issues with your code:

1. You use `req(input$type)` which should be `req(input$offense)`. That's the reason why no plot (or rather no error message) shows up when running your code
2. The second issue is the filtering of your data. Noz sure what you had in mind ... but to filter your data you can use `subset(data_4, offense %in% input$offense & date >= input$date[[1]] & date <= input$date[[2]])`

The full reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)

bbox = c(left=-95.8, bottom=29.4, right=-95.0, top=30.0)
map <- get_stamenmap(bbox, zoom = 10, source="stamen")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Crime Location"),
  sidebarPanel('Choose the type of offense to show in plot:',
               checkboxGroupInput("offense", label = "Type of offenses...",
                                  choices = list("Murder" = 'murder',
                                                 "Robbery" = 'robbery',
                                                 "Aggravated assault" = 'aggravated assault',
                                                 "Burglary" = 'burglary',
                                                 "Rape" = 'rape'),
                                  selected = 'Murder'),
               dateRangeInput("date", "Date range:",
                              start  = "2010-01-01",
                              end    = "2010-12-08",
                              min    = "2010-01-01",
                              max    = "2010-12-08",
                              format = "yyyy/mm/dd",
                              separator = " - ")
  ),
  mainPanel('Performance Plot',
            plotOutput('myplot')),
  position = 'left'
)


server <- function(input, output){
  output$myplot <- renderPlot(
    {
      req(input$offense)

      ggmap(map) + stat_density2d(data = subset(data_4, offense %in% input$offense & date >= input$date[[1]] & date <= input$date[[2]]),
                                  aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), geom = 'polygon') +
        scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "red") +
        scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0, 0.8)) +
        geom_point(data = subset(data_4, offense %in% input$offense),
                   aes(x = lon, y = lat), size = 0.5) + 
        guides(fill = FALSE, alpha = FALSE) +
        ggtitle('Crime in Houston TX')
      
    }
  )
  
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: hi thank you so much for the help. When I try to use your code .I got an error message of object offense not found. any idea?

Comment: Ay. Sorry. As I dropped what you called "data" the `geom_point` should now use "data_4", i.e. `geom_point(data = subset(data_4, offense %in% input$offense)`. I just edited my post to correct this.

Comment: Thx! Now I was trying to add color in the geom_point by doing colour = "offense" , but they all turn out to be the same color when I choose more than one option. Any idea?

Comment: Neither do I. (; Switching to `%in%` (should) show the total amount of crimes when the user checks multiple types. However, I have no clue how to visualize the different types seperatly except for making a facetted plot by e.g. adding `facet_wrap(~offense)`.

Comment: ... map `offense` on color, i.e. `geom_point(..., aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = offense)`. (without quotes (; )